# Add fill listbox at runtime in windows form application c#

Tags: c#, winforms

Hello I have to make this gui below and add items to the listbox states during runtime.

[image]

I have been able to make this code below which list 10 states to the second listbox. But for the first listbox I have to be able to add the states to the list at runtime, I have no idea how to do this. Can anyone please help me to solve this?

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for(int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
    {
        listTenStates.Items.Add(listStates.Items[listStates.Items.Count - i]);
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: please read [ask]

Comment: Copy/paste your actual code well formatted in the question, please. Do not put an image that is not very usable.

Comment: Sometimes screenshots are useful if code isn't working but please post code as text initially. We'll ask for a screenshot version if it will help. Now, you don't seem to have asked a question - you say you "have been able" to do this task, so what are you stuck on?

Comment: Right now I'd say it looks ok, though it'll add the last ten in reverse order, maybe that's what you want. It will crash if there are less than ten items in the first box. If you're seeking help with the "add them to the first list box programmatically" part that could mean a few different things- maybe you have to read them out of the excel using jet db driver or epplus, maybe you can convert the excel to text and use file.readalllines, maybe it even qualifies as programmatic if they're pasted into your form load.. tell us so we can help and edit your question a bit to be just about that part

Comment: ok sorry im new here will edit the post

Comment: What is the name of your first list box?

Comment: listStates for first listbox
listTenStates for second listbox

Answer (score 1):

I'll give this a general answer. But you should read the site's guides.

The `public Form1()` method executes at run time. You can add items to a list box after `InitializeComponent();` like this:

```
statesList.Items.Add("State 1");
///and so on
statesList.Items.Add("State 50");
```

or like this

```
listBox1.Items.AddRange(new string[] { "state 1", "state 50" });
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have all states as string inside the list, you can add those to your listStates as described below

```
  public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            List<string> states = new List<string>() { "State1", "state2" };//This should contain all the states 
            foreach (var state in states)
            {
                listStates.Items.Add(state);
            }
        }
    }
```